# Cannot remap <F5> in Vim

Tags: vim, vundle

I use vundle and some other plugins for Vim

When I execute `:map <F5>` I see `<F5>          :!ruby %<CR>`

But I have defined in the end of my `~/.vimrc` after all `Bundle` instuctions these mappings:

```
imap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
nmap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
omap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
cmap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
vmap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
smap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
xmap <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
map <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>
```

Also if I execute in Vim `:map <F5> <Esc><Esc>:w<CR>:!ruby %<CR>` it works the way it should. Seems like my mappings in .vimrc are ignored.

Why is that? How to remap `<F5>` ?

**UPDATE**:

```
:verbose map <F5>
   <F5>          :!ruby %<CR>
        Last set from ~/Dropbox/home/.vim/bundle/ruby-menu.vim/plugin/ruby-menu.vim
```

Actually I don't need ruby-menu plugin, gonna trash it. Btw, why does it remap my mappings?

Comment: You can check with `:verbose map <F5>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check where this got defined via

```
:verbose map <F5>
```

It seems to be from [this line](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ruby-menu.vim/blob/master/plugin/ruby-menu.vim#L9) in the ruby-menu plugin. That plugin should offer `<Plug>`-mapping targets that would allow you to change the mapped keys, or disable the mapping altogether. You could file a defect against it.

The plugin overrides your mapping, because by the time the plugin loads, your .vimrc already has finished processing.

To workaround, you need to define the mapping *after* the plugin loads, with one of these methods:

1. use the *after* directory and put your overriding mapping definitions into `~/.vim/bundle/ruby-menu.vim/after/plugin/ruby-menu.vim`
2. use another location (e.g. `~/.vim/after/plugin/mappings-override.vim`) that is sourced after the plugins (check with `:scriptnames`)
3. try the override from your `~/.vimrc` via `autocmd VimEnter * map <F5> ...`, thereby delaying the actual definition until after the plugins have been initialized

Comment: @zuba, not exceptional at all, Ingo's answers are *always* like this one.